# Cant use InternetAddress with umlauts anymore after switching to com.sun.mail:javax.mail

Tags: jakarta-mail

we recently switched from `javax.mail:mail` to `com.sun.mail:javax.mail`.
Since then the following code fails:

```
new InternetAddress("chr@möllers.de", false).validate();

Caught: javax.mail.internet.AddressException: Domain contains control or  whitespace in string ``chr@möllers.de''
javax.mail.internet.AddressException: Domain contains control or whitespace in string ``chr@möllers.de''
```

The implementation of `InternetAddress#validate()` has obviously changed. A few additional lines concerning CRLF checks are followed by this snippet:

```
else if (c <= 040 || c >= 0177) {
    throw new AddressException(
            "Domain contains control or whitespace", addr);
```

Every char >=  177 is treated as control or whitespace - which is wrong, e.g. for umlauts (ö = 246).
So the exception message is misleading.

*Did the change of validate() introduce a bug?*

By now, Internet email addresses may contain umlauts encoded in punycode. Thats why i expected to be safe passing a string with umlauts.

*Is InternetAddress intended to be used with an encoded String in this case?*

Thanks in advance

## Update to Bill Shannons answer

The nicely formatted Groovy script mentioned in my comment:

```
@GrabResolver(name='snapshots', root='https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/snapshots/', m2Compatible='true')
@Grab("com.sun.mail:javax.mail:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT")

import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress

new InternetAddress("chr@möllers.de", false)
```

## Update: test with latest snapshot

```
import org.junit.Test;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;

public class ValidateEmailTest {

    @Test
    public void test() throws AddressException {
      new InternetAddress("chr@möllers.de", true).validate();
      new InternetAddress("chr@möllers.de", false).validate();
    }
}
```

The test runs successfully (not throwing an AddressException) with the latest snapshot 1.6.0-SNAPSHOT that is currently from Tue Feb 21.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use of non-ASCII characters in domain names requires support for [RFC 6530](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6530), [RFC 6531](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6531), and [RFC 6532](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6532).  Both the client and the server need to support these new standards.  I've added such support to JavaMail 1.6; you can download a development SNAPSHOT release as described on the [JavaMail web page](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#Development_Releases).  You need to ensure that the server supports the SMTPUTF8 extension, and you need to set the Session property `mail.mime.allowutf8` to `true`.

If you're able to test this new support for internationalized email addresses using a real mail server, please let me know your experiences, good or bad, at javamail_ww@oracle.com.  Thanks.

Comment: Our infrastructure does not yet support non-ASCII characters, indeed.
However, I'm still surprised that the following Groovy script fails.



@GrabResolver(name='snapshots', root='https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/snapshots/', m2Compatible='true')
@Grab("com.sun.mail:javax.mail:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT")

import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress

new InternetAddress("chr@möllers.de", false)



I'm using the current snapshot 1.6.0 and the outcome is:



javax.mail.internet.AddressException: Domain contains control or whitespace in string ``chr@möllers.de''



Thank you.

Comment: Added the above mentioned script to the original question.

Comment: I know nothing about Groovy but I suspect it isn't actually getting the right JavaMail jar file.  The equivalent trivial Java program works fine.

Comment: Yes, dependency resolution didn't result in the expected latest snapshot version.
I created a simple maven project with an unit test.
**Umlauts in email addresses are working with 1.6.0-SNAPSHOT.**
We will use the release version 1.6.0 when it is available.
Thank you!